# Android convert string to class

Tags: java, android, class

I am saving my `String` that I am getting from `MyActivity.getClass().getName()` to `SharedPreferences` (Just basic key-value structure).

Then I want to convert this String back to my MyActivity.class somehow so I would not write tons of switch-case.

Comment: Did you try using reflection?

Comment: Why is `sharedPreferences.getString()` not working for you?

Comment: @MuratK. I am doing it, just want then convert String to Class

Comment: @JMLord , yeah, thanks going to use it.

Comment: Sounds like you are interested in serialization.

Comment: @Andreas I think the object would be too big to save it in this case.

Comment: Are you interested in storing the name of the class or the object itself? Or is `MyActivity` a supertype for a strategy implementation where there are no field. In which case perhaps `MyActivity` should be an enum.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you

```
try
{
    Class klazz = Class.forName("my.package.MyActivity"); //without the .class
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, you have to add the path, in this case "mypackage.tests." and the name of your class is `Test`

```
Class.forName("mypackage.tests.Test")
```